# Angular2 - RC5 Http.delete fails

Tags: angular, angular2-http

Im **upgrading my angular2 app to RC5 and now the Http.delete operation fails** (before it gets executed) when it was succeeded before.

Here the package.json:

    `"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.5",`

Here is how Im using it:

```
deleteUser(id){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.delete(this._usersUrl + '/' + id, options)
         .map(res => { 
             return <User>res.json()
         })
        .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

**While debugging I can see that it gets until http.delete** and **while executing the delete operation something crashes** (DELETE is not sent to server). I have checked the [docs for Http api](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html#!#delete-anchor) in case I'm missing some arguments but I think they are fine.

Checking more carefully, **none of the delete operations get executed but others HTTP operations work fine. Any clue?**

The error I get is the following:

`platform-browser.umd.min.js:6 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of nullBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.min.js:6ExceptionHandler.call @ core.umd.min.js:7next @ core.umd.min.js:10generatorOrNext.object.schedulerFn @ core.umd.min.js:10t.__tryOrUnsub @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11t.next @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11t._next @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11t.next @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11t._finalNext @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11t._next @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11t.next @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.min.js:10onError @ core.umd.min.js:10onHandleError @ core.umd.min.js:10e.handleError @ zone.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:1e.runGuarded @ zone.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:1NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded @ core.umd.min.js:10NgZone.runGuarded @ core.umd.min.js:10outsideHandler @ platform-browser.umd.min.js:7e.invokeTask @ zone.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:1e.runTask @ zone.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:1invoke @ zone.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:1
platform-browser.umd.min.js:6 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.min.js:6ExceptionHandler.call @ core.umd.min.js:7next @ core.umd.min.js:10generatorOrNext.object.schedulerFn @ core.umd.min.js:10t.__tryOrUnsub @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11t.next @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11t._next @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11t.next @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11t._finalNext @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11t._next @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11t.next @ Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.min.js:10onError @ core.umd.min.js:10onHandleError @ core.umd.min.js:10e.handleError @ zone.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:1e.runGuarded @ zone.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:1NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded @ core.umd.min.js:10NgZone.runGuarded @ core.umd.min.js:10outsideHandler @ platform-browser.umd.min.js:7e.invokeTask @ zone.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:1e.runTask @ zone.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:1invoke @ zone.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:1
platform-browser.umd.min.js:6 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
    at Request.Body.text (http.umd.min.js:6)
    at Request.getBody (http.umd.min.js:7)
    at eval [as _subscribe] (http.umd.min.js:6)
    at e.subscribe (Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11)
    at e._subscribe (Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:11)
    at e.call (Rx.min.js?cb=e6b3f62:7)`

Answer (score -2):

As Angular 2.0 is released try upgrading your code to the stable version.